# Help with 301 redirect from subdomain to root domain

Tags: apache, htaccess, 301-redirect

I need to forward existing subdomain links to the root domain as the subdomain no longer exists. I have tried so many different lines of code in my `.htaccess` file and can not get the redirect to work.

The links to the subdomain look like: `http://sub.example.com/dir/y99bb4`

Can anyone suggest any code for me?

Answer (score 7):

To redirect requests for `sub.example.com/uri` to `example.com/uri`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect requests for `sub.example.com/uri` to `example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick. I just need to redirect from sub.yourdomain.com/uri to yourdomain.com (no uri)

Comment: @Lin Thanks for the information. I've updated my answer with a rewrite rule that drops the path when redirecting.

Comment: thanks but it's not working for me. Maybe I'm placing it in the wrong spot in my .htaccess 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

[I tried the code here]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

[I also tried the code here]

other working 301s are here

I can't seem to format this so it's easy to read.

Comment: @Lin I've tested this on a live site and the rules are working for me. Is there still a DNS record for the subdomain in your domain control panel? Or, if you're using nameservers and managing the subdomain with cPanel or similar, is there still a subdomain entry in your cPanel account? Removing either of these will break the redirection because there still needs to be a record that the subdomain existed. Let me know if that's not clear and I'll try to help.

Comment: If I want to use `https`, would I still use the above code as-is, but with `https` in the bottom URL, instead of `http`?

Comment: @PaulShryock Yes, that would work.